# Application proxy returning 404

Tags: shopify

I've set up an application proxy for my app, but when I try to access the URL in my test shop, it returns a 404 error.

Proxy URL: `http://localhost:3000`

Path: `tools/track`

Test Shop Proxy URL: `http://harber-inc8996.myshopify.com/tools/track`

When I go to that proxy URL (which I believe you can see for yourself), it returns a 404 error.

Now that I'm writing this out, I'm wondering...is the issue that the Proxy URL can't be `localhost`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use localhost as a proxy.

The reason behind this is that Shopify actually has to be able to send a request to the proxy location. From Shopify's perspective localhost is... itself.

You have to provide a publicly accessible address for your proxy.

There are a couple of ways to do this. The easiest/most popular way to go is either with [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) or [showoff.io](http://showoff.io). Localtunnel is free but gives you different URL every time you start it. Showoff will give you a permanent address but costs money. Such is life.